How would the number of covalent bonds affect alien life?
How would aliens based on e.g. Nitrogen which can form 3 instead of 4 covalent bonds or even elements with which can form only 2 covalent bonds be affected by that?
Would e.g. oxygen based aliens be possible?
Now, of course this all being speculative fiction there is a lot of leeway and e.g. just taking carbon there are sheer infinite lifeforms that it can theoretically create, but would some properties stick out and have a major impact that is likely to show in such aliens' biology?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The problem with this question is that we don't actually know enough about how life could express itself to answer it. We have one and only one data point to work with: Earth. Everything else is a guess (no matter how many letters after the guesser's name). Nobody knows what a nitrogen-based lifeform would chemically look like, so the question of covalent bonds is irrelevant. But, more to the point of Stack Exchange... do you have a problem to solve? Because as written, this appears to be a request for an education, not a request for help solving a specific and well-defined problem.

The first problem you have is to explain why you have more nitrogen than carbon or oxygen. Carbon and Oxygen are far more common in the universe and on planets than nitrogen. Their nuclei contain an even number of protons, which makes them more stable. A plausible reason is that under the right conditions of temperature and pressure, a planet could could have an ammonia ocean with ice at the bottom.
The second issue is that carbon's importance in life chemistry is due to a unique feature: the elements of carbon's period (carbon, nitrogen, oxygen, fluorine) form covalent bonds by sharing electrons to form an "octet" of four pairs of electrons. In carbon, all four of these electron pairs are involved in bonding, which makes hydrocarbon chains invulnerable to chemical attack (kinetically stable) as there is no easy place to attack them. Nitrogen and Oxygen atoms use only some of their electron pairs in bonding, which makes them much more reactive. Sometimes silicon (below carbon in the periodic table) is suggested as an alternative to carbon, but silicon hydrides are also easily attacked because there are empty d orbitals in the silicon atom of similar energy to the valence orbitals.
Life as we know it has three main types of compound: protein, fat and carbohydrate. Protein is made of specific sequences of 20 amino acids, with a backbone of -NH-CHR-CO- so one third nitrogen. The R group varies by amino acid but is mainly carbon and hydrogen in most cases.
Fat is almost exclusively hydrocarbon with a small amount of oxygen, and is the most efficient form of energy storage (on an energy-weight basis) for oxygen breathing organisms. Nevertheless, some life forms (such as cephalopods, the octopus/squid family) store energy as protein. Fatty acids and related molecules have a long hydrophobic tail and a hydrophilic end, which enables them to self-assemble into cell membranes (phospholipid bilayer) with the hydrophilic heads pointing into/out of the cell and the hydophobic tails forming the middle layer of the membrane. The same principle would apply in ammonia.
Carbohydrate has a hydrocarbon backbone with OH groups on it. On heating it decomposes to carbon and water. It is used in plants to make cell walls and is useful as a source of energy (less weight efficient than fat but more easily acessible) In ammonia solution, life would likely evolve a nitrogen equivalent of hydrocarbon with a carbon backbone with NH2 groups instead of OH groups.
All of these rely on a mostly "saturated" backbone based on carbon atoms with no double bonds (the main exception is protein, where half the carbon atoms in the backbone are double bonded to oxygen in C=O groups.)
Nitrogen is not good on its own at forming long chains of atoms. One issue is that the N2 molecule is very stable with a triple bond between the two nitrogen atoms. This means that molecules with chains of several nitrogen atoms tend to be unstable, sometimes explosively so (azides for example) because they can release energy by decomposing to N2. With carbon the opposite is true: the carbon-carbon triple bond is unstable, and acetylene C2H2 rearranges explosively to other compounds.
There is one class of organic molecules containing a lot of nitrogen which is very important life, although it is not one of the big three by weight (protein, fat and carbohydrate.) That is the aromatic nitrogen bases. These contain roughly equal amounts of nitrogen and carbon, forming ring systems with alternating single and double bonds. DNA's backbone is made of hydrocarbon (sugar) and phosphate, but the genetic information is carried in four nitrogen bases: two with the purine C5H4N4 ring system: adenine C5H5N5 and guanine C5H5N5O, and two with the pyrimidine C4H4N2 ring system: cytosine C4H5N3O and thymine C5H6N2O (uracil is used instead of thymidine in RNA). Caffeine is another nitrogen base in this family. Adenosine phosphates, derived from adenine, are very important in metabolism as well as in genetics.
Compounds such as these are believed to have been present on the early Earth (adenine is known to be formed by polymerisation of hydrogen cyanide HCN). In an environment where the ocean is ammonia, they might take on a structural role (instead of being used primarily for genetics and metabolism as in life as we know it.)
Birds excrete waste nitrogen in the form of guanidine CH5N3. The guanidine group is found in several important organic molecules, including the proteinogenic amino acid Arginine. Mammals excrete the less nitrogen rich urea CON2H4
In summary:

Nitrogen is not as good as carbon at forming long chains, because it has a nonbonding pair of electrons that leaves it more vulnerable to attack, so you are unlikely to get rid of carbon completely. Also compounds tend to be unstable with respect to decomposition to nitrogen gas, and can be explosive.
Nitrogen is rarer in the universe than carbon or oxygen, but could form a basis of life on a planet with an ammonia ocean.
Nitrogen is used in the backbone of proteins of life as we know it forming a third of the atoms, but the side chains are mostly hydrocarbon. Nitrogen forms a greater proportion of the atoms in aromatic bases, up to 50% (could be more.) In life in an ammonia ocean, such bases could form a structural role (instead of being used mainly for genetics and metabolism as in life as we know it)
Metabolism in an ammonia world would be different than in an oxygen rich world. Perhaps organisms would "photosynthesise" by extracting nitrogen from the atmosphere and turning it into complex molecules, and "respire" by turning it back into nitrogen. This has the interesting consequence that organisms wouldn't need to ingest a gas such as oxygen in order to breathe. Also fat as an energy storage medium is optimised for an oxygen rich world, but could still find use in a nitrogen rich world for cell membranes. Carbohydrates with -OH groups  would largely be replaced by their nitrogen analogs with -NH2 groups.


You can use markup: eg.  CO[sub]2[/sub]

It isn't just the number of covalent bonds that are important, but the properties of the compounds built from those bonds. Nitrogen is important to life as it is found in nearly all proteins. However, there are not many compounds built out of nitrogen and no carbon. It is not likely that a large organism would be created from nitrogen chemistry.
Several explosives are based on nitrogen including Nitroguanidine. That suggests that your aliens might not have a long half-life.

Explosives containing the nitro group NO2 are explosive because of the oxygen in the nitro group, not the nitrogen itself. Where the molecule contains both NO2 and carbon (or other elements that burn readily) a highly energetic (explosive) rearrangement can occur where the oxygen becomes directly bonded to the carbon.  This occurs much faster than obtaining oxygen from the atmosphere as in normal burning.

There are however explosives such as sodium azide NaN3 (used in airbags) where the explosion is driven entirely by the energetic rearrangement of nitrogen atoms into N2 gas

@LevelRiverSt, you don't need a nitro group to get a nitrogen explosive.  Consider, for example, azidoazide azides.

@Mark that is covered in my second comment. Azides are less energetic than organic nitro compounds, but in some cases can be more sensitive. There are plenty of non-nitrogen explosives, for example organic peroxides, too. Curiously, the carbon-carbon triple bond is unstable while the nitrogen-nitrogen triple bond is very stable (acetylene C2H2 is more energetic than benzene C6H6 and will rearrange explosively, while azides will rearrange explosively to form N2, and the benzene analog N6 is unknown.)
